# The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to ArrayList<Integer>

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I'm trying to put the `ints`into the `Arraylist myList` but Eclipse is pointing to the error:
`The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to ArrayList<Integer>`

I tried to convert from primitive type into Object type but still getting the same error. COuld smb please help me out with that ?

```
import java.util.*;
    public class RemoveDuplicates {

        public static void main(String[] args){

            int[] myArray = {1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,8,9,9,99};
            ArrayList<Integer> myList = new ArrayList();

            for(int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){
                for(int j = 1; j < myArray.length; j++){
                    if(myArray[i] == myArray[j]){
                        myList.add(myList[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't get elements from a list using this syntax.

```
myList[i]
```

Which is only valid for arrays. Instead, use the

```
myList.get(i);
```

method. More likely though you meant to put `myArray[i]` there.

Comment: oh, I've found my mistake and have asked the question in a wrong way. Thanks though! Fixed!